# Devserver Proxy w/ Axios

Tags: express, vue.js

I cannot seem to get the devServer: proxy setting working in my vue / express app.

My vue.config.js file is in the root of my client folder and looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      'api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5000'
      }
    }
  },
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ]
}
```

I'm sending a request from the frontend using axios like this:

```
const response = await http.get("/api/auth/authenticate");
```

My express app is running on localhost:5000 and I've configured endpoints as such:

```
...other endpoints
app.use("/api/auth", authController);
```

The request appears in my network tab as:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/api/auth/authenticate
```

and returns a 404 error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What about if you type `http://localhost:5000/api/auth/authenticate` directly into the browser address bar? Does that hit the relevant route or do you get a 404?

Comment: @skirtle Yep that returns the expected result

Comment: It may be worth confirming that the config file is being respected at all. Try putting `port: 6789,` in the `devServer` section, just above the `proxy` config. That should start your dev server on a different port, confirming that the file is doing something.

Answer (score 0):

Since now it is not fetching from your backend, but searching for some static content (hitting 8080, vue must be running on this port). Try using, so that it get redirected to proxy:

```
    proxy: {
      '^/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5000',
        ws: false,
        changeOrigin: true
      },
```

Or just '/api' instead of '^/api'

Comment: Unfortunately did not change anything. Is there a way I can check the proxy is actually being created at all? When I run npm run serve to start the client, there's so much webpack build output I can't see if anything else there.